# Can I make 3D plots in Charticulator? If so how?

Tags: plot, 3d, powerbi, data-visualization

I have a very simply question: Can Charticulator (https://charticulator.com/ - which is by Microsoft) make 3D plots?

I have been able to make 2D plots, but so far as of May 9th, 2021, despite Googling as well as Youtubing, I could not find how to make a 3D plot, nor could I find any confirmation anywhere that charticulator cannot make 3D plots.

Is there simply a lack of information on the internet on how to make 3D plots in Charticular, or does it not support 3D plots as of the time of posting this question?

Thank you for everyone's help!

P.S. Stackoverflow is not letting me create a charticulator tag in the Tags section, so I put a bunch of other related tags. Can the community help me create a charticulator tag?

Comment: Charticulator documentation doesn't mention about 3D plots. However, if you would like to create 3D plots there is a Microsoft Garage project "Charts 3D" which can be downloaded for free from Microsoft store. Link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/charts-3d/